# No qualifying bean of type 'my class' available Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Не понимаю почему возникает ошибка. Если в класс `PersonDAOHibernate` добавляю конструкторы (по умолчанию или с параметром SessionFactory), то они вызываются т.е. бин создаётся.
В стуктуре проекта видно, что Idea подсвечивает главный класс серым, но к чему это она - непонятно.
ApplicationContext.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:th="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd"
>

    <context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.example.dao"/>
    <th:annotation-driven/>
    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <util:properties id="hibernateProperties">
        <prop key="hibernateDialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
    </util:properties>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
          p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
          p:packagesToScan="org.example.dao"
          p:hibernateProperties-ref="hibernateProperties"/>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager"
          p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>
</beans>
```

Класс PersonDAOHibernate:

```
package org.example.dao;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import javax.annotation.Resource;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * * @author Andrey Fyodorov
 */
@Transactional
@Repository("personDao")
public class PersonDAOHibernate  implements PersonDAO {
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(PersonDAOHibernate.class);
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Resource(name="sessionFactory")
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<Person> index() {
        //language=HQL
        return getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Person c").list();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public Person show(int id) {
        return getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().byId(Person.class).load(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(@NotNull Person person) {
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().update(person);
        LOG.info("Person saved with id: "+ person.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(int id) {
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().delete(id);
        LOG.info("Person deleted with id: "+ id);
    }

    @Override
    public void create(@NotNull Person person) {
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().save(person);
    }
}
```

Класс Person:

```
package org.example.dao;

import javax.persistence.*;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

/**
 * * @author Andrey Fyodorov
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private int age;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Person() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.printf("%d %s %d %s",id, name, age, email);
    }
}
```

Класс Application:

```
package org.example;

import org.example.dao.Person;
import org.example.dao.PersonDAOHibernate;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

/**
 * * @author Andrey Fyodorov
 */
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext =
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        PersonDAOHibernate daoHibernate = applicationContext.getBean(PersonDAOHibernate.class);
        Person kira = daoHibernate.show(3);
        kira.print();
        applicationContext.close();
    }
}
```

Структура проекта:
[image: Структура проекта]

Сама ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.example.dao.PersonDAOHibernate' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1127)
    at org.example.Application.main(Application.java:14)
```

Интрерфейс `PersonDAO` скидывать не стал, там просто 5 методов, которые я реализую в `PersonDAOHibernate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ получен эмпирическим методом. Буду очень благодарен, если кто-то объяснит почему это работает.
Решение: в 14 строке `Application` передавать имя интерфейса, а не класса.

```java
PersonDAO daoHibernate = applicationContext.getBean(PersonDAO.class);
```

**UPD**
Так же всё работает, если в `PersonDAOHibernate` не реализовывать интерфейс `PersonDAO` (мейн менять не нужно).